Change background color of Container without rebuilding widgets
I have a simple widget called a LineBox that changes the background color of a Container when the mouse hovers over it using a MouseRegion. However, this appears to be very inefficient as it requires Flutter to rebuild this widget as well as each of its children whenever the hovered state is changed, which will be a problem in the future as I intend to have many of these together in a Column. The main issue with this approach arises when I place another stateful widget inside of the LineBox - everything resets its state if the mouse moves outside of the box. My code is below:
class LineBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget? child;
  final double indent;

  const LineBox({
    super.key,
    this.child,
    this.indent = 0,
  });

  @override
  State<LineBox> createState() => _LineBoxState();
}

class _LineBoxState extends State<LineBox> {
  var _hovered = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MouseRegion(
      onEnter: (event) => setState((){
        _hovered = true;
      }),
      onExit: (event) => setState((){
        _hovered = false;
      }),
      child: Container(
        color: _hovered ? Colors.red : null,
        height: 40.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: widget.indent),
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}

So far, I've tried stacking the LineBox below its child with a Stack, but this means the MouseRegion triggers the onExit event whenever the mouse moves over the child. I also tried wrapping the child widget in a KeyedSubtree with a UniqueKey, which does nothing.

The state is preserved when I use a GlobalKey instead of a UniqueKey in the KeyedSubtree. However, I'm still looking for a solution that don't require generating tons of global keys...

I think it is pretty difficult not to rebuild the children if you change the color of their background. Flutter tries to avoid unnecessary builds. What you check when happens if the child you have is a a StatefulWidget? Maybe it could help not using a child but wrap both this widget and the child inside a Stack that could help Flutter to know that they are just layered on top of each other.
In general I would only start worrying about something like this if you encounter performance problems.

You can try the property hoverColor of the InkWell widget

@NguyễnĐứcThành Thanks, this is definitely the simplest solution (- don't forget to set onTap to a non-null value, and make sure the highlight, splash, and focus colors are all transparent)

You can try to separate the background container from its children in this way:
class _LineBoxState extends State<LineBox> {
  final ValueNotifier<bool> _hovered = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(
          child: ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
            builder: (BuildContext context, bool value, Widget? child) {
              return Container(
                color: value ? Colors.red : null,
              );
            },
            valueListenable: _hovered,
          ),
        ),
        MouseRegion(
          onEnter: (event) => _hovered.value = true,
          onExit: (event) => _hovered.value = false,
          child: widget.child,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


Very nice solution, @NguyễnĐứcThành's comment seems to be the simplest way to solve my problem but this is definitely useful for something that requires more customisation

I think, and it could be wrong, but there is just one case when LineBox will be rebuild and child not:
LineBox(
  child: const SomeChildWidget(),
)..

As child is const, there will no rebuild for this child widget.

I think you misunderstand const here it doesn't mean that the widget won't be rebult but that the Widget object won't get created everytime a rebuild is made

Yes, I think you are totally right here. thank you for clarification!
